# LeafLet: add array object into slider

Tags: javascript, leaflet

If I have an Array of Objects that were parsed from JSON such as:

```
 var results =  [
  {
  "time": 1478542485,
  "lat": 50.64470631082,
  "lng": 13.9902814650912
   },
   {
  "time": 1479542485,
  "lat": 50.64570631082,
  "lng": 13.9902814650912
   },
   {
  "time": 1578542485,
  "lat": 50.64473631082,
  "lng": 13.9902814650912
   }
 }
]
```

How can I push them into array so that each array object will look like:

```
 var marker = L.marker([50.64470631082, 13.9902814650912], {time: 1478542485});
```

This is what I have done so far

```
var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
        var latln = new L.LatLng(results[i].lat, results[i].lng);
        var time =   results[i].time;
        var t = '{time: ' + time + '}';
        var mark = L.marker(latln, t.replace("\'",""));
        markers.push(mark);
    }
```

I have the LatLng right, but the time doesn't come out right. I am trying to use the [Leaflet Slider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) and display data onto map.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "object json array".  JSON values are just strings.  When you have there is just a standard JavaScript Array of Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty straight forward use of `Array.prototype.map`.  `.map()` is called with a function (in this case an arrow function) that produces a new element that is based on the existing element (the argument passed to the function).  The return value from map is a new Array containing the new elements.

```js
// ------------------8<----------------------
// LeafletStub is just here to provide mock ups of the functions called in the `L` object 
function LeafletStub() {
}
LeafletStub.prototype.LatLng = function(lat, lng) {
  return `lat: ${lat}, lng: ${lng}`; }
LeafletStub.prototype.marker = function(latlng, time) {
  return `latlng: {${latlng}}, time: ${time.time}`; }
var L = new LeafletStub();
// ------------------8<----------------------

var inputObj = [{
  "time": 1478542485,
  "lat": 50.64470631082,
  "lng": 13.9902814650912
}, {
  "time": 1479542485,
  "lat": 50.64570631082,
  "lng": 13.9902814650912
}, {
  "time": 1578542485,
  "lat": 50.64473631082,
  "lng": 13.9902814650912
}]

// answer really starts here.
var markers = inputObj.map( element => L.marker(L.LatLng(element.lat, element.lng), { time: element.time } ) );

console.log(markers);
```

Comment: @Tenz this is arrow function . maybe leaflet doesn't support it . use simple function syntax . it will work for sure

Comment: @Tenz "normal" function version: `var markers = inputObj.map( function(element) { return L.marker(L.LatLng(element.lat, element.lng), { time: element.time } ) } );`

Answer (score 1):

Combine the answers of Mahi and Tibrogargan, I make it works by using this

```
   var markers = results.map( function(b){
        return (L.marker(new L.LatLng(b.lat, b.lon), { time: b.time}))
    });
```

Thank you, guys

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var results =  [
  {
  "time": 1478542485,
  "lat": 50.64470631082,
  "lng": 13.9902814650912
   },
   {
  "time": 1479542485,
  "lat": 50.64570631082,
  "lng": 13.9902814650912
   },
   {
  "time": 1578542485,
  "lat": 50.64473631082,
  "lng": 13.9902814650912
   }
 
]
var a= results.map(function(b){
return [[b.lat,b.lng],{"time":b.time}];
});


console.log(a);
```

Comment: This one is right, but it doesnt give me the latlng object.